# Extra bytes on stack when trying stack smashing in C

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, stack-overflow

I am learning about stack smashing and found an example which for me does not work as expected.
I have the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

GetInput() {
  char buffer[8];
  gets(buffer);
  puts(buffer);
}

main() {
  GetInput();
  return 0;
}
```

when running the code in GDB with break points at "GetInput()" and "gets(buffer)" and displaying the stack at the first and second break point  gives me the following: [stack while running code with break points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnHOA.png)

Looking at the stack there are 20 bytes being pushed to it. That 20 byte should be the following: 8 bytes for the buffer, 4 bytes for the old value of EBP and another 4 bytes for the return address. and there is still another 4 bytes which I am not sure where it is coming from.
Could someone please explain why is there 20 bytes instead of 16.

Comment: What is the `GetInput` return type? What does *EBP* means? In general the best is to check assembly code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: @tilz0R EBP is a Stack Data Pointer Register.

Comment: Did you disable stack-smashing protection/detection when building?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have used : gcc -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -o <name of file> <name of file.c>

Comment: 18 years ago there was a new C standard released...  maybe focus on learning correct C programming rather than "stack smashing".

Answer (score 0):

Padding

Depending on the compiler used and the version of that compiler and even the optimization flags, different amount of padding may be pushed on the stack in different places for different reasons.  Your compiler may be inserting stack canaries to detect buffer overflows.  It may be trying to improve alignment or cache behavior.  It may simply be inefficient and wasting space.

There's no way to say for certain, as every compiler is different, and the precise layout of local variables is not mandated by any spec or ABI.